# Como puedo setear el color del JButton en esta linea de código?:

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica

```
new JButton(new PersonAction(new Person(miResultSet.getString("name"), miResultSet.getString("identification"))))
```

Si se puede referir a este objeto que creo dinamicamente con un While de otra manera, Díganmelo por favor. GRACIAS.

Comment: Y porque no declaras los objetos fuera del while y los inicializas dentro??
Y cuando dices add(), es añadir a que?? a un marco, a una lista..

Comment: Se agregan a un JPanel, Y no los inicializo antes por que los botones se crean mediante un while recorriendo mi BD, entonces lo que necesito es que el dato del color se guarde en mi BD para cada boton y ya despues se recorrido por el while cada vez que se abra el programa.

Comment: Ahí te he dejado una respuesta de como podrías hacerlo. Se admiten sugerencias :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te voy a dejar un pequeño ejemplo de como podrías hacerlo dentro del **while** para setear el color de fondo de esos botones con valores que tengamos en una tabla de nuestra BD.

**<>** Nuestra **tabla** con los datos almacenados..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**<>** Un método que maneje el color de fondo del botón según valor

```
public final void establecerFondoBoton(String ident, JButton btn) {
        btn.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        switch (ident) {
            case "rojo":
                btn.setBackground(Color.RED);
                break;
            case "azul":
                btn.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                break;
            case "verde":
                btn.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                break;
            case "rosa":
                btn.setBackground(Color.PINK);
                break;
            case "amarillo":
                btn.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                btn.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                break;    
        }
    }
```

**<>** Nuestro bucle `while()`

```
while (result.next()) { // mientras tenga un valor siguiente  
                System.out.print("Id:" + result.getInt(1)+" | ");
                System.out.print(" Nombre:" + result.getString(2)+ " ");
                System.out.println(" Identificacion:" + result.getString(3));
                String name = result.getString("name");
                String identification = result.getString("identification");
                Person persona = new Person(name, identification);
                PersonAction accionPersona = new PersonAction(persona);
                //btn = new JButton(persona.getName());
                JButton btn = new JButton(accionPersona);
                establecerFondoBoton(identification, btn);
                this.add(btn);
                //listaBotones.add(btn);
            }
```

**Resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Dentro del **`while`** estamos obteniendo el **name** e **identification** de nuestra tabla alojada en BD, en los cuales nos estamos apoyando para darle un Nombre y Color a nuestros respectivos botones creados dinámicamente.

Comment: Oh hermano eres genial! Tu codigo es precioso, Me enseñaste mucho!

Comment: Espero que te haya servido. Un placer hermano. :)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto:

```
ArrayList <JButton> botones= new ArrayList();
botones.add(new JButton(new PersonAction(newPerson(miResultSet.getString("name"), miResultSet.getString("identification")))));
for (JButton boton : botones)
{
    // Haces lo que quieras
}
```

Comment: Y no hay algo que sea así?: add(new JButton(new PersonAction(new Person(miResultSet.getString("name"), miResultSet.getString("identification"))),setBackground(Color.yellow)));

Comment: Hola Chuchip. Para que una respuesta sea de calidad has de explicar qué tiene mal el planteamiento de la pregunta y cómo tu respuesta da solucion. No basta con pegar un codigo y ya. Mira  [answer] para más info. Un saludo